# urxvt vim transparent colorscheme

Tags: linux, vim, urxvt, transparency

I have urxvt running in real transparency mode using xcompmgr. Everything looks great but I would like my vim colorscheme to respect the transparency setting. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim itself won't be able to apply varying alpha levels to its colors. You'll have to change the `Normal` highlight in your colorscheme from:

```
hi Normal ctermbg=<whatever> ctermfg=<whatever>
```

to:

```
hi Normal ctermfg=<whatever>
```

In short: remove your colorscheme's backgound color definition.

Answer (score 1):

And in case you don't know or don't wanto to look for your current foreground color, you can also set the backgour color to none

`hi Normal ctermbg=NONE`